# URL index.php remove not working

Tags: magento-1.7, url, url-rewrite, htaccess

I took my Magento store from a live site to a localhost. Magento's version is 1.7, and it's running over WAMP on my localhost. The homepage was working fine, but all URLs from there gave 404 error from the server. However, if I included index.php manually in each URL, everything worked fine. I figured out that going to Admin/System/Configuration/General/Web, I had enabled the option for URL rewrites that removes index.php. When I disable this option, my site works properly. So, I searched about this problem, and tried different things, but I have not been able to solve it.

I have mod_rewrite enabled, that's the first thing I checked.

I have seen lots of posts recommending to overwrite either an .htaccess file or a httpd.conf (Apache's    configuration file) file.

My .htaccess looks like this right now:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule .* ../get.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

- I also checked that in httpd.conf I had AllowOverride al, and indeed, among other things, I have the following:

  ## code:

  ```
  #
  # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
  # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
  #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
  #
  AllowOverride all
  ```

My site is still not working when enabling the option for removing index.php from all URLs.

Does anyone have an idea of what I might be missing? Any help will be much appreciated :-)

Comment: have you enable server rewrites from admin panel?

Comment: I have enabled server rewrites yes

Comment: ok, please goto root folder once and check .htaccess file is there or not. or better to download fresh .htaccess file and import to root

Comment: Thanks for answering. My .htaccess file is not in my root folder. Instead, it's in the /media folder. I'm editing my original post to include my code in my .htaccess file, could you please tell me if I'm missing something?

Comment: so, working fine now right?

Comment: Not yet, I added my cofe in .htaccess, could you kindly take a look at it? Maybe I missed something? I don't really understand the language used in this file, so I don't know what could I be missing.

Comment: please reindex, remove cache and browser cache everything and refresh the website and try

Comment: Still not working :\ I saw in other posts that maybe httpd-vhosts is the issue. I checked it, its code includes  AllowOverride All Require local

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the conversion is that different from apache2 to httpd (I'm assuming you're on centos) but try this:

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
```

Comment: Thanks for answering; in which file should I add this code? I am on Windows 10 using WAMP. I don't have such /var/www folder. I have /var inside my Magento folder and www inside my WAMP folder.

Comment: You'll need to open up the vhost files available via clicking the wamp logo in system tray then hover over apache then click  httpd-vhosts.conf and you'll find the vhost then, my original answer didn't include the end bit for some reason so make sure you add </Directory> to the end of the bit I've suggested putting in.

Comment: Thank you. I just added the code you provided but still not working. I cleared Magento's and browser's cache, and reindexed everything from Admin panel before trying.

Comment: If you click wamp then hover over apache then hover over extensions and make sure rewrite is ticked

Comment: Indeed I have rewrite_module ticked, yes.